# Access toolbar buttons clipped in small window

Tags: interface

When my Blender toolbar (or menu etc.) doesn't have enough screen space, the right hand side get's clipped so it starts losing buttons...

[image: Blender - clipped toolbars]

Is there a way to customise the toolbars so that all buttons are visible?
Typically in Windows this would be done via draggable/floating/wrapable toolbars, changing their orientation or an overflow dropdown button - but I haven't figured out how to enable any of these for Blender yet!

I've had a poke through the Python API, but can't see much support for customising the interface. Is this a possibility?

I've rearranged the workspace as best I can to maximise horizontal width of each area, but don't have enough vertical height to stack areas vertically, so as soon as I have 3+ areas I start losing buttons (eg: UV Editor, 3d view, outliner).

To compound the problem, I need minimum UI scale of %125 to see everything clearly (ideally more!).

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: with middle mouse button you can drag these buttons, so you can access to all of them.

Comment: Well hold me down! Very useful thanks.

Comment: You can also hover the mouse over the buttons and use the mouse wheel.

Comment: Another "ahhh" moment for me! I checked the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/tool_system.html#toolbar) before raising the initial question... are these tips documented anywhere?

Comment: Whilst testing out your suggestions, I found a 1px place where you can resize the vertical toolbar on the left into 2 columns. Is this possible with the top toolbar?